# Airflow 2.2 TriggerDagRunOperator wait_for_completion behavior

Tags: airflow, mwaa

I have a question about the `TriggerDagRunOperator` , specifically the wait_for_completion parameter.

Before moving to Airflow 2.2, we used this operator to trigger another DAG and a `ExternalTaskSensor` to wait for its completion.

In Airflow 2.2, there is a new parameter that is called `wait_for_completion` that if sets to True, will make the task complete only when the triggered DAG completed.

This is great, but I was wondering about wether the worker will be released between pokes or not. I know that the `ExternalTaskSensor` used to have a parameter `reschedule` that you can use for pokes larger than 1m which will release the worker slot between pokes - but I don’t see it in the documentation anymore.

My question is if the `wait_for_completion` parameter causes the operator to release the worker between pokes or not? From looking at the code I don’t think that is the case, so I just want to verify.

[image]

If it isn’t releasing the worker and the triggered DAG is bound to take more than 1m to finish, what should be the best approach here?

We are using MWAA Airflow 2.2 so I guess deferred operators are not an option (if it is a solution in this case)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For Apache-Airflow>=2.6.0:**

Assuming you have [Triggerer](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/cli-and-env-variables-ref.html#triggerer) process running you can use [Deferrable Operators](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/authoring-and-scheduling/deferring.html). Thus the operator will defer (no occupy worker slot) when needed - according to the logic of the specific operator. To set it up simply use:

```
TriggerDagRunOperator(..., deferrable=True)
```

**For Apache-Airflow<2.6.0:**

When using `wait_for_completion=True` in `TriggerDagRunOperator` the worker will not be released as long as the operator is running. You can see that in the [operator implementation](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/d08284ed251b7c5712190181623b500a38cd640d/airflow/operators/trigger_dagrun.py#L174-L197). The operator use `time.sleep(self.poke_interval)`

As you pointed there are two ways to achieve the goal of verifying the triggered dag completed:

1. DAG A Using `TriggerDagRunOperator` followed by `ExternalTaskSensor`
2. Using `TriggerDagRunOperator` with `wait_for_completion=True`

However other than resources issue which you mentioned the two options are not really equivalent.

In option 1 if the triggered DAG fails then the `ExternalTaskSensor` will fail.

In option 2 consider:

```
from airflow.operators.trigger_dagrun import TriggerDagRunOperator
my_op = TriggerDagRunOperator (
    task_id='task',
    trigger_dag_id="dag_b",
    ...,
    wait_for_completion=True,
    retries=2
)
```

if the `dag_b` fails then `TriggerDagRunOperator` will retry which will invoke another DagRun of `dag_b`.

Both options are valid. You need to decide which behavior suitable for your use case.

Comment: Thanks Elad for the answer. The only missing part is, how can I set a sensor/triggerDagRunOperator that will sleep between pokes, if possible, at MWAA 2.2.2? I know of deferrable operators, but they are not available right now in MWAA.

Comment: You can't. TriggerDagRunOperator is not a sensor. while sleeps it occupy the worker.

Comment: Is there a sensor that can release the worker slot between pokes then?

Comment: ah wait, I can see there is a mode parameter to the base sensor, so I can use the ExternalTaskSensor with reschedule mode to make the sensor sleep between pokes, right?

Comment: `ExternalTaskSensor` is sensor so yes but your question was on `TriggerDagRunOperator`. The `TriggerDagRunOperator` can not release worker, `ExternalTaskSensor` can just like all sensors can.

Comment: So, `ExternalTaskSensor` release the worker? I thought that between pokes, all sensors keeps running in the worker, hence keep it busy. Do you have any example?

Comment: @SantiagoP Sensors has `mode` parameter which can be configured. You can read about the differences between `poke` and `reschedule` modes:
https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/d7b85d9a0a09fd7b287ec928d3b68c38481b0225/airflow/sensors/base.py#L88-L99

Comment: Airflow now supports `TriggerDagRunOperator` with deferrable support from V2.6.0.